# Having trouble starting Jenkins: "java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/share/java/jenkins/war/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF (No such file or directory)"

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, jenkins, startup

I just downloaded the Jenkins WAR, version 1.651.1.  I’m trying to set it up on my Amazon Linux box.  I’m running Java 1.7.  I moved the WAR into its own directory, /usr/share/java/jenkins, and then set `JENKINS_HOME` to be that directory.  Then I ran the command listed here — https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Starting+and+Accessing+Jenkins.  Looked so simple on the web site.  But I got the below error:

```
[davea@mydevbox ~]$ java -jar /usr/share/java/jenkins/jenkins.war 
Running from: /usr/share/java/jenkins/jenkins.war
webroot: EnvVars.masterEnvVars.get("JENKINS_HOME")
Apr 19, 2016 9:29:34 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Beginning extraction from war file
Apr 19, 2016 9:29:34 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Winstone shutdown successfully
Apr 19, 2016 9:29:34 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
SEVERE: Container startup failed
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/share/java/jenkins/war/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:171)
    at winstone.HostConfiguration.getWebRoot(HostConfiguration.java:280)
    at winstone.HostConfiguration.<init>(HostConfiguration.java:83)
    at winstone.HostGroup.initHost(HostGroup.java:66)
    at winstone.HostGroup.<init>(HostGroup.java:45)
    at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:145)
    at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at Main._main(Main.java:307)
    at Main.main(Main.java:98)
```

What else do I need to do to get Jenkins started?

**Edit:** Output in response to the suggestion given ...

```
[davea@mydevbox ~]$ sudo useradd jenkins
[davea@mydevbox ~]$ sudo chown -R jenkins:jenkins /usr/share/java/jenkins/jenkins.war 
[davea@mydevbox ~]$ 
[davea@mydevbox ~]$ sudo su - jenkins
[jenkins@mydevbox ~]$ java -jar /usr/share/java/jenkins/jenkins.war
Running from: /usr/share/java/jenkins/jenkins.war
webroot: EnvVars.masterEnvVars.get("JENKINS_HOME")
Apr 21, 2016 4:46:08 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Beginning extraction from war file
Apr 21, 2016 4:46:08 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Winstone shutdown successfully
Apr 21, 2016 4:46:08 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
SEVERE: Container startup failed
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/java/jboss/standalone/deployments/jenkins.war/war/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:171)
    at winstone.HostConfiguration.getWebRoot(HostConfiguration.java:280)
    at winstone.HostConfiguration.<init>(HostConfiguration.java:83)
    at winstone.HostGroup.initHost(HostGroup.java:66)
    at winstone.HostGroup.<init>(HostGroup.java:45)
    at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:145)
    at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at Main._main(Main.java:307)
    at Main.main(Main.java:98)
```

Answer (score 5):

I think it is a permission related issue.

I guess the user and group owner isset to a different user than what jenkins was trying to run as. Try to set it correctly with:

```
$sudo chown -R <jenkins_user><jenkins_group> /usr/share/java/jenkins/
```

Comment: I edited my question to show the output of doing what you suggested.  Same error.  I created a jenkins user on my system, although I'm not sure why that would cure things.

Answer (score 3):

“java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/share/java/jenkins/war/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF (No such file or directory)”

Guys be chill.

Just run below command.

## mkdir /var/cache/jenkins;chown jenkins:jenkins /var/cache/jenkins;

and the start the app.

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same issue. Unable to change the user, I changed the hosted port by appending `--httpPort=9090` to my java run command.

`$ java -jar /usr/share/java/jenkins/jenkins.war --httpPort=9090`

Answer (score 1):

My two cents: not only must be jenkins user be the *owner* of  `$JENKINS_HOME`, it looks like it also has to be the *owner* of `jenkins.war` (not just have access to it). Found out the hard way while configuring sytemd unit file for Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the userid that you are using is not the owner of `JENKINS_HOME`.

This has happened to me on Vagrant, when trying to use the `jenkins` user on a  `JENKINS_HOME` owned by `vagrant`. `jenkins` **did** have write permissions to on `JENKINS_HOME`, but it is not enough: it has to be the owner.

I learned this because when I tried `sudo -u jenkins touch file-in-jenkins-home` I got `touch: setting times (...): Operation not permitted`. And then I found https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/64848/cannot-touch-m-a-writable-file

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had this problem because a user named "jenkins" was already created on my Mac.

After:

1. uninstalling the broken Jenkins with `'/Library/Application
   Support/Jenkins/Uninstall.command'`,
2. removing the "jenkins" user,
3. and re-installing from https://jenkins.io/download

--> everything worked smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue after i accidently deleted the cache from /var/cache/jenkins. I resolved it by manually creating the jenkins folder in /var/cache/ with the same permission which is there in /var/lib/jenkins and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I have an old jenkins version 1.641, and downloaded the war file of 2.240.1, when run

```
java -jar jenkins.war
```

I got similar errors:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   c:\jenkins.jenkins\war\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF (Access is denied)
>           at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
>           at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Unknown Source)
>           at java.io.FileOutputStream.(Unknown Source)
>           at java.io.FileOutputStream.(Unknown Source)
>           at winstone.HostConfiguration.getWebRoot(HostConfiguration.java:278)
>           at winstone.HostConfiguration.(HostConfiguration.java:81)
>           at winstone.HostGroup.initHost(HostGroup.java:66)
>           at winstone.HostGroup.(HostGroup.java:45)
>           at winstone.Launcher.(Launcher.java:172)
>           at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:362)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at Main._main(Main.java:375)
>           at Main.main(Main.java:151) 2020-02-07 22:06:19.010+0000 [id=1]     SEVERE  winstone.Logger#logInternal: Container startup
>   failed java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   c:\jenkins.jenkins\war\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF (Access is denied)
>           at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
>           at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Unknown Source)
>           at java.io.FileOutputStream.(Unknown Source)
>           at java.io.FileOutputStream.(Unknown Source)
>           at winstone.HostConfiguration.getWebRoot(HostConfiguration.java:278)
>           at winstone.HostConfiguration.(HostConfiguration.java:81)
>           at winstone.HostGroup.initHost(HostGroup.java:66)
>           at winstone.HostGroup.(HostGroup.java:45)
>           at winstone.Launcher.(Launcher.java:172)
>           at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:362)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at Main._main(Main.java:375)
>           at Main.main(Main.java:151)

it is found that the folder `c:\jenkins\.jenkins\war` did not exist.

After manually created the folder, the new Jenkins works.