# JENKINS.SF (Access is denied)

Tags: jenkins

I have downloaded jenkins war and trying to run as standalone server.

java -jar jenkins.war

I am using java 1.8 version.
A similler post i found but none of the answer is working :

[Having trouble starting Jenkins: "java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/share/java/jenkins/war/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF (No such file or directory)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36745970/having-trouble-starting-jenkins-java-io-filenotfoundexception-usr-share-java)

I am getting below error:

```
sumankumar@TL110 MINGW64 ~/Desktop/jenkins
$ java -jar jenkins.war
Running from: C:\Users\sumankumar\Desktop\jenkins\jenkins.war
webroot: $user.home/.jenkins
Jul 24, 2018 11:03:32 AM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log initialized
INFO: Logging initialized @975ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog
Jul 24, 2018 11:03:32 AM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Beginning extraction from war file
Jul 24, 2018 11:03:32 AM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Jetty shutdown successfully
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\sumankumar\.jenkins\war\META-INF\JENKINS.SF (Access is denied)                                                                                                             
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at winstone.HostConfiguration.getWebRoot(HostConfiguration.java:278)
        at winstone.HostConfiguration.<init>(HostConfiguration.java:81)
        at winstone.HostGroup.initHost(HostGroup.java:66)
        at winstone.HostGroup.<init>(HostGroup.java:45)
        at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:148)
        at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:363)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at Main._main(Main.java:344)
        at Main.main(Main.java:160)
Jul 24, 2018 11:03:32 AM winstone.Logger logInternal
SEVERE: Container startup failed
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\sumankumar\.jenkins\war\META-INF\JENKINS.SF (Access is denied)                                                                                                                
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at winstone.HostConfiguration.getWebRoot(HostConfiguration.java:278)
        at winstone.HostConfiguration.<init>(HostConfiguration.java:81)
        at winstone.HostGroup.initHost(HostGroup.java:66)
        at winstone.HostGroup.<init>(HostGroup.java:45)
        at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:148)
        at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:363)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at Main._main(Main.java:344)
        at Main.main(Main.java:160)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried to do same with `sudo` command ??

Comment: I am using windows , so no sudo command instead i run command prompt as an administrator still same error.

Comment: Even try with windows power shell still same error.

Comment: ok so check the env variables JAVA_HOME is it set properly ??

Comment: also check that the port 8080 is not occupy by any other process

Comment: I did check...i have tried running on different port too :

Comment: java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=8181

Comment: Yes JAVA_HOME env is present.I tried lot's of thing..seems some weried thing.

Comment: strange let me google then .. i get back to you soon..add me on skype ionic.fiverr@gmail.com

Comment: Sure, Thank You!