# Jenkins service not starting anymore after system update

Tags: jenkins

I have updated my redhat server where jenkins was installed. After reboot, the jenkins service is not starting up.

getting the below error

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
> "/opt/data/jenkins/war/"META-INF/MANIFEST.MF (No such file or
> directory)

MANIFEST.MF file is present under /opt/data/jenkins/war/META-INF . Any idea what this could be? Also the " in /opt/data/jenkins/war/ looks a bit strange to me.

Comment: Have you checked permissions?

Comment: I checked permissions for files/folder under /opt/data/jenkins and it looks ok. Does system update change permissions as well?

Comment: Not necessarily. Are you starting Jenkins with the `jenkins` user? Also try changing the directory ownership to the jenkins group and the user.

Comment: yes and files in /opt/data/jenkins are owned jenkins:jenkins

Comment: There are few suggestions here. Have a look : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36745970/having-trouble-starting-jenkins-java-io-filenotfoundexception-usr-share-java

Comment: Saw that already. Unfortunately nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We fixed this by looking at systemctl parameters which were wrong. Restart jenkins after correcting that solved the problem